# Contract creation from another contract succeeds, then fails?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, remix

I have a first contract with some very basic functionality :

```
contract ContractA {

    uint public supplyA;

    function ContractA (uint _supply) { 
        supplyA = _supply; 
    }

    function setNewSupply() { 
        supplyA = 1000;
    }
}
```

I want to create a new instance of this contract from within a second contract :

```
import './ContractA.sol';

contract ContractB {

    uint public supplyB;

    event LogSupplyA(uint supplyA);

    function ContractB () {
        supplyB = 100;
    }

    function deployA() returns (address) {
        ContractA newContract = new ContractA(250);

        newContract.setNewSupply();
        LogSupplyA(newContract.supplyA());

        return newContract;
    }
}
```

When I run the `deployA()` function on `contractB` in Remix, it returns an address for a `contractA` instance. However, if I use that address to look at that instance afterwards it cannot be found

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'op' of undefined

Omitting the following lines solves the problem:

```
        newContract.setNewSupply();
        LogSupplyA(newContract.supplyA());
```

But leaving the lines in does make the `LogSupplyA` event display 1000 as value instead of 250, and does return an address for my new instance.

I don't fully understand what is happening here. Why is an updated value shown in my event and is an address returned for my new contract instance, if apparently something went wrong and my contract was not instantiated?